# Right align function issue

Tags: python

I have just started learning python and i am having trouble getting this function to work. Thanks in advance :)

So here the code:

```
def RightAlign (text, textR):
text = str ("word")
textR = '{:>30}'.format(text)
'                        '
return print(textr)
#=============================#
print("What school do you go to")
School = str(input(""))
RightAlign(School)
```

And here is the error: TypeError: RightAlign() missing 1 required positional argument: 'textR'

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RightAlign` method is defined with two parameters, and you are only passing one. I suspect that you only want to pass it the one parameter.

So change your method definition to this:

```
def RightAlign (text):
```

Furthermore, I noticed in your `RightAlign` method you are over-writing the text with `str(word)`. I don't know if this was part of your troubleshooting, but you are never going to get the output you want with that. So I suggest you remove that line. Your code will look like this:

```
def RightAlign (text):
    textR = '{:>30}'.format(text)
    return print(textR)

print("What school do you go to")
School = str(input(""))
RightAlign(School)
```

DEMO:

```
What school do you go to
school
                        school
```

Just some small notes to help improve your code. You don't need to be returning the call to print the way you are doing here:

```
return print(textR)
```

Instead, you can do this:

```
def RightAlign (text):
    return '{:>30}'.format(text)
```

Then when you call it simply do this:

```
print(RightAlign(School))
```

or

```
result = RightAlign(School)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the detail, this helped me a lot. :)